# Strange build errors with Wix projects

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I have a strange build problem in a large solution that includes two Wix projects.  Both projects give the following build error:

error LGHT0195: The Windows Installer XML variable 'WixUICostingPopupOptOut' is declared in more than one location.

The file cited for the error is Common.wxs, which I cannot find anywhere.  How can I address these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with the [experiment held by Bob Arnson](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/05/20/its-time-to-experiment/) to troubleshoot a hard-to-catch issue. In the results of that experiment ([part 1](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/05/28/experimental-results-part-i/) and [part 2](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/10/09/experimental-results-part-ii/)) Bob advises how to avoid build errors related to the WixUICostingPopupOptOut variable.